# All data in dataframe is only stored in one cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bc['Price_P'] = None
bc['Price_P'][:-1] = np.diff(bc['Price'])

d = {'col1': [bc['Price_P']]}
afgeldata = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
afgeldata
```

With `bc['Price']` being the price of bitcoin per day, stored in csv file, and `bc['Price_P']` being the difference of price per day.`Afgeldata` outputs all the data in once cell.

```
    col1
0   0 5697.9 1 2864.5 2 714.3 3...
```

But i need all the data for each day separate in the column. How do I fix this?

Comment: Changing `d = {'col1': [bc['Price_P']]}` into `d = {'col1': bc['Price_P']}` shoud solve it (you've created an outer list with its first cell containing the price list).

Comment: That's it. Thank you